# Using acro and mhchem inside of chemfig

Tags: chemfig, mhchem, acro

After [a blog post by Joseph Wright](http://www.texdev.net/2012/08/25/exploring-chemfig-customising-appearance/), I wanted to use `mhchem` in `chemfig`. All went well, until I decided to include acronyms by the `acro` package. With the following MWE, the acronym is defined as used, but not included in the acronym list.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\DeclareAcronym{boc}{short=Boc,long=\textit{tert}-butyloxycarbonyl}

% From http://www.texdev.net/2012/08/25/exploring-chemfig-customising-appearance/
\makeatletter
\def\CF@node@content{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter%\expandafter\expandafter%
  \printatom\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter%\expandafter\expandafter%
  {\csname atom@\number\CF@cnt@atomnumber\endcsname}%
  \ensuremath{\CF@node@strut}%
}
\makeatother
\renewcommand*{\printatom}[1]{{\ce{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\sffamily

\acifused{boc}{Boc is used}{Boc is not used}

\chemfig{\acs{boc}HN-R-NH2}

\acifused{boc}{Boc is used}{Boc is not used}

\printacronyms

\end{document}
```

[image: Acronym not in acronym list]

When the code from the blog post is removed, all works fine again, but I really liked being able to use `\ce` from within `\chemfig`. Also, it made `\chemfig` use the sans-serif text font instead of the serif math font, which was something I wanted.

I tried using five `\expandafter`s around the `\printatom` macro. This did fix the acronym issue, and the font still is the same as the surrounding sans-serif text font, but parsing by `\ce` is no longer done correctly. Note the non-subscript 2:

[image: Contents not parsed by mhchem]

Any suggestions how to get both `acro` and `mhchem` to work inside of `chemfig` would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Due to your redefinition the `\acs` command is processed more than once, but as the first processing -- this is an educated guess -- are only done to measure the content the write commands from acro aren't executed and so it doesn't write the needed `\acro@used@once` to the aux-file but only `\acro@used@twice` from the actual typesetting.

You would get a similar behaviour also if you used acro inside `align` (tested) and probably `tabularx` and other environment which process their content twice. So imho it is a bug: acro should check this case.

You should notify the author, as a workaround you can try the following. Be aware that from the point of view of acro this key has been used twice. So a special style for "single" occurances will not work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{chemfig,amsmath}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\DeclareAcronym{boc}{short=Boc,long=\textit{tert}-butyloxycarbonyl}

%% From http://www.texdev.net/2012/08/25/exploring-chemfig-customising-appearance/
\makeatletter
\def\CF@node@content{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter%\expandafter\expandafter%
  \printatom\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter%\expandafter\expandafter%
  {\csname atom@\number\CF@cnt@atomnumber\endcsname}%
  \ensuremath{\CF@node@strut}%
}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_protected:Npn \acro@used@twice #1#2#3#4
  {
    \bool_if:cF {g__acro_#1_in_list_bool}
    {\acro@used@once {#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}
    \cs_gset_nopar:cpn {acro@#1@twice} {#1}
    \tl_if_empty:nF {#2#3#4}
      { \seq_gput_right:cn {g__acro_#1_pages_seq} { {#2}{#3}{#4} } }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatother
\renewcommand*{\printatom}[1]{{\ce{#1}}}

\begin{document}


\sffamily

\acifused{boc}{Boc is used}{Boc is not used}

\chemfig{\acs{boc}HN-R-NH2}

\acifused{boc}{Boc is used}{Boc is not used}

\printacronyms

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is related: http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/1820/problem-zwischen-dem-paket-acro-und-ltxtable

Comment: @clemens yes, but imho instead of patching all sorts of commands it would be easier to extend/improve my work around: if a previous once command is missing the twice version should simply fall back to the once version.

Comment: I've discovered that when you use `\ac` instead of `\acs` or `\acl` inside such an environment you only get the short form printed out. That also seems like a bug, which the above workaround does not fix. [I've created a bug report here.](https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/acro/issues/92/acronyms-in-environments-which-process)